# Add object constraint follow path

Tags: animation

I have an object which is following a path using (Add object constraint). My main animation is fine, but when I want to duplicate the same object with the path animation the object is going astray. The main object animation in the middle which has the cursor to the selected position is fine, but everything else goes odd when I move them around the scene.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because *Follow Path* will take into account the location of the object relatively to the world origin, so when you move the curve AND the planet object, the planet object moves twice as it is attached to the curve, and as it changes its location relatively to the world origin.

To fix that, you can either:

- Duplicate the curve and planet and only move the curve, the planet will move along, or
- Move both, then select each planet and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (to bring back to world origin)

Comment: This was the best solution: Move both, then select each planet and press Alt G (to bring back to world origin) Thanks!